# Optimal learning time per day

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, memory

Is there any 'value' for optimal learning time per day? I'm thinking of something like attention span, but more general.

Comment: Do you mean time of day or amount of time per day? What kind of learning are you considering?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most effective maximum work duration per day?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4514/what-is-the-most-effective-maximum-work-duration-per-day)

Comment: Also http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/how-long-should-i-work-before-taking-a-break